# Angular HTTP Service - Test Fails

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-test

I am learning Angular, and wrote a service that simply gets some data using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http). I am having a lot of trouble writing a unit test that verifies the service gets data successfully. I have posted my source code and test spec for the service.

**example.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // get some sample data from an remote server
  getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
}
```

**example.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ExampleService } from './example.service';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('ExampleService', () => {
  let service: ExampleService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ExampleService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // this is the test that fails
  it('getData should return the correct value',
    (done: DoneFn) => {
      service.getData().subscribe(value => {
        console.log('test never reaches this line');
        // tslint:disable-next-line
        expect(value['userId']).toBe(1);
        done();
      });
    });
});
```

The `getData should return the correct value` test fails with an error of `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms`. I noticed that the test never enters the `subscribe()` method. The really weird thing is that when I run `getData()` outside of the testing framework, it pulls data back successfully. I have spent hours trying to fix this and have tried to find a solution, but came up empty-handed.

Comment: The http testing module is only if your are directly testing an http service. If the goal is to the test the service you can simply mock the call. Try using the following guide https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services

Answer (score 1):

Service methods don't necessarily need to be unit tested with `TestBed.configureTestingModule` since they are just regular classes. It's only necessary if you want to test it within a component or if you want angular to inject the dependencies for you.

So it's also possible to instantiate your service manually in each test and give it the dependencies it needs. That's also the default method for testing pipes and directives as well.

To **unit test** anything with network requests, the network methods (or anything outside the "unit") should be mocked. In this case the `httpClient` methods are outside your service and these shouldn't be tested, so they get mocked.

**1) To mock methods**, use `jasmine.createSpyObj`:

```
let httpClient: { get: jasmine.Spy };
let service: ExampleService;
httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);

beforeEach(() => {
  service = new ExampleService(<any> httpClientSpy);
});
```

**2) To mock the server responses**, we can create a helper function that will wrap the data in a promise, which could be stored in a "test-utils" folder.

• successful response:

```
export function responseData<T>(data: T) {
  return defer(() => Promise.resolve(data));
}
```

• an error response:

```
export function responseError<T>(errorObject: any) {
  return defer(() => Promise.reject(errorObject));
}
```

**3) Now you can test** service methdos that make network requests by defining the server response in your http spy:

```
it('should return "Yay!"', () => {
  const expectedResponse = "[{ hero: 'StackOverflow' }]";

  // return expectedResponse when anyone calls get
  httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(responseData(expectedResponse));

  service.getData().subscribe(response => {
    expect(service.heroes.length).toEqual(1)
  }, fail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are making unit tests of http requests, you cannot use your real service and make the real http request. So, you have to mock your service, create fake service and a similar getData() method that returns an observable too and same data like the real method. You can do this by creating a stub class and using the RxJS of, that is an observable and can be used by your test class.

Below is an example of how to do that.

```
export class ExampleServiceStub {

  constructor() { }

  // get some sample data from an remote server
  getData() {
    return of(
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Data name'
            }
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the of() you can put the data that the real http request will return. You have to inject your stub service like you injected the real service in the test class.